# Enviar un tipo de datos a un método Genérico en c#

Tags: c#

bien,  tengo un aplicación en C# con el Framework 4.7.1, necesito enviarle a una método genérico el tipo de dato en tiempo de ejecución de esta forma:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type tt = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    string cadena = GetValueRand<tt>();
}

private string GetValueRand<T>()
{
    //....
    return "";
}
```

Pero me da error en tt, como puedo hacer para lograr esto?

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta en SO Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957817/calling-generic-method-with-type-variable)

Comment: Hola, qué problema hay con hacer `string cadena = GetValueRand<int>();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, la única manera de conseguir lo que quieres es usando `Reflection`.

Lo primero, debes convertir tu método a `public` para que pueda obtenerse una referencia usando `Reflection`:

```
public string GetValueRand<T>()
{
    //....
    return "";
}
```

Luego debes obtener la referencia del método e invocarla. Sería algo así:

```
Type tt = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = typeof(Form3).GetMethod("GetValueRand");
System.Reflection.MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(tt);
string cadena=(string)generic.Invoke(this, null);
```

**Editado**

Si quieres seguir manteniendo el método como privado, puedes obtener el método usando `BindingFlags`:

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = typeof(Form3).GetMethod("GetValueRand", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Veo que OP no me ha contestado a mi comentario en su pregunta. No crees que sería más sencillo hacer `string cadena = GetValueRand<int>();` ?

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra obviamente. Pero imagino que cuando quiere hacerlo de esta manera es porque en tiempo de compilación no se sabe el tipo a utilizar, por eso utiliza `GetType`

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra de hecho en su pregunta especifíca: _necesito enviarle a una método genérico el tipo de dato en **tiempo de ejecución** de esta forma_

Comment: Sigo sin verlo... si en el código se escribe `Type tt = Type.GetType("System.Int32");` ya se sabe que el tipo que se requiere es un `Int32` por lo que el resto del código me parece sobrante. Bueno, es una opinión que no se si puede escribirse en los comentarios o no. Un  saludo

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra por supuesto que puedes comentar tus dudas :). No voy a intentar meterme en la cabeza del op,pero creo que es una de esas raras ocasiones en el que alguien ha creado un [mcve]. Es decir, lo que ha puesto es un ejemplo,pero creo que en su programa si tendría sentido ya que supongo que por alguna razón no sabe el tipo en tiempo de compilación.